# Excel 2010: Pull Images Contained in Folder into Excel Cells

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I have a folder which contains a spreadsheet. Alongside this spreadsheet (within the same folder which the spreadsheet is contained in), is a folder named "images". This folder may have anywhere between 0 and 10,000 images contained within it as separate png files.

The files are named like this:

00001.png

...

00010.png

...

00100.png

...

01000.png

...

10000.png

(where "..." symbolised a gap between multiple files, keep in mind that the files increase in increments of 1, e.g: 00001.png is directly followed by 00002.png).

I require that the aforementioned spreadsheet (contained within the same folder as the "images" folder, but not within the "images" folder itself) is able to pull through however many of these images happen to be present to the 10,000 long cell range of 'C3:C10002' (C3 to C10002).

The images should only be pulled through if present and if not present, the spreadsheet / VBA macro/script should not crash to the detriment of the user.

This is extremely likely to require an Excel VBA macro of some sort that can be run at the press of a button (I know how to insert macro buttons).

The script should not alter the size/dimensions of the image(s). Containing cells should have their width and height adjusted to fit the images perfectly.

I understand that Excel cells have a maximum height / width and that the images will have to be pre-optimised to fit the cells. I'd like the images to display as thumbnails of roughly 3 inches wide by 1.6 inches tall (unsure what that is in pixels!)

I'd greatly appreciate any help... Even if you can't suggest something which accomplishes all of this, "best shots" will be warmly welcome.

Comment: Various fudgings around in Python (which is what I know) but unfortunately Python modules such as xlutils seem to nuke formatting and therefore I'm reaching out for help from someone who knows more about VBA and excel-friendly scripts / languages

Answer (score 0):

I have this code that helps add an image to the sheet, you could modify it to loop within multiple files and add the image file based on the file name:

```
Sub AddPictures()
    DirForImages = "S:\TCarnevale\Overdrive Images\"
    Dim counter As Integer
    Dim vsn As Boolean
    Dim myrange As Range


            ActiveSheet.Pictures.Delete
            Range("Y15").Select
            For I = 0 To 400

                DoEvents

                'Set picture range depending on count, *modify below set of code to add/remove styles*


                    Set Rng = Range("A8")


                    'get the style number to pull the image from the directory
                        styleinfo = ActiveCell.Value

                        If Dir(DirForImages & styleinfo & ".jpg") <> "" Then
                            Set pic = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture(DirForImages & styleinfo & ".jpg", False, True, 1, 1, 1, 1)
                            'resize the image
                            With pic
                                .Height = 100
                                .Width = 75
                                .Left = Rng.Left
                                .Top = Rng.Top

                            End With



                            counter = counter + 1
                        ElseIf Dir(DirForImages & styleinfo & ".png") <> "" Then
                            Set pic = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture(DirForImages & styleinfo & ".png", False, True, 1, 1, 1, 1)
                            'resize the image
                            With pic
                                .Height = 100
                                .Width = 75
                                .Left = Rng.Left
                                .Top = Rng.Top

'
                            End With



                            counter = counter + 1
                        Else


                            counter = counter + 1
                        End If



                    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

            Next
            Range("Y17").Select


Range("A1").Select


End Sub
```

This code is checking for PNG files as well as JPG files and re sizing them in pixels. You can use [this calculator](http://www.unitconversion.org/typography/inchs-to-pixels-y-conversion.html) to convert inches to pixels.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see this working out the way you expect.

First of all, trying to display 10,000 PNG files in a spreadsheet strikes me as a seriously bad idea. The memory requirements could easily lock up your computer or crash Excel.

Secondly, settings cell sizes in VBA can be confusing. Cell height is specified in points by default, while width is measured based on the default font.

https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/Change-the-column-width-and-row-height-72f5e3cc-994d-43e8-ae58-9774a0905f46

Third, you'll need to have images with the correct dimensions and ppi/dpi resolution. Excel respects printing dimensions, so a 300 pixel image at 96ppi will display differently than a 300 pixel image at 150ppi.

Fourth, displays aren't measured in inches like paper sizes. Modern displays have a variety of resolutions, from 72dpi on the low end to over 300dpi for some mobile devices and Retina/HiDPI screens. This will affect how large on-screen a picture will look.

Having said all that:

I would batch process images in a program like Photoshop to set them (for your needs) at 300 pixels wide, 96ppi.

I would NOT try to show 10,000 images in a spreadsheet. Divide it up into several files.

Finally, some quickly cobbled-together code that might be a starting point:

```
Dim InsertLoc As Range
Dim i As Integer
Dim PName As String
Sub Macro1()
i = 2
PName = ""
Columns("A:A").ColumnWidth = 43
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For i = 1 To 10
Set InsertLoc = Range("A" & CStr(i))
InsertLoc.Select
PName = "C:\Users\user\Desktop\" & i & ".jpg"
Rows(i).RowHeight = 150
On Error Resume Next
 ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert PName
 Next i
 Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: You might also look at this topic:

http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/92490/finding-and-pasting-images-into-a-specific-cell

Comment: You make a lot of sense there :') basically I have a Python script that loads URLs one after the other (which are stored in a spreadsheet). The Python script then saves full-page screenshots of each URL to a folder. What I need is an output that has the URLs and images next to each other. This could be a paginated HTML table or something similar. Problem is, I don't know how to generate that table from the URLs in the spreadsheet and (separately) the matching images from the "images" folder. I'm sure there's a better way to do this than pulling it all into excel! Any particular suggestions?